# How to add Hangouts chat bot in the gmail's chat?

Tags: gmail, chat, bots

I created a Hangouts Chat bot but I can only discuss with him on chat.google.com.
On mail.google.com, I turned "Chat on" but i can see the bot.

Is it possible to add it ? If not, is there a possibility to create an extension or a gmail add-on to integrate it ?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Did you find an answer for this?

Comment: I didn't find an answer for my question.